# How expressions designating temporary objects are xvalue expression?

Tags: c++, value-categories, xvalue, prvalue

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), I am trying to understand expressions that yield xvalues, and I ended up with this summary:

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> - ...
> - any expression that designates a temporary object, after temporary
>   materialization.

[Temporary materialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) is:

> A prvalue of any complete type T can be converted to an xvalue of the
> same type T. This conversion initializes a temporary object of type T
> from the prvalue by evaluating the prvalue with the temporary object
> as its result object, and produces an xvalue denoting the temporary
> object.

And *per my understanding* from the above quote, temporary materialization involves converting the prvalue into an xvalue to initialize the created temporary; and that's mean that whenever prvalue is materialized, an xvalue expression appears. So I found myself have to understand when exactly a prvalue is materialized. then I have checked [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) from cppreference:

> Temporary materialization occurs in the following situations:
>
> - 1- when binding a reference to a prvalue;
> - 2- when performing a member access on a class prvalue;
> - 3- when performing an array-to-pointer conversion
>   or subscripting on an array prvalue;
> - 4- when initializing an object of type std::initializer_list from a braced-init-list;
> - 5- when typeid is applied to a prvalue
> - 6- when sizeof is applied to a prvalue
> - 7- when a prvalue appears as a discarded-value
>   expression.
>
> Note that temporary materialization does not occur when initializing an object from a prvalue of the same type (by direct-initialization or copy-initialization): such object is initialized directly from the initializer. This ensures "guaranteed copy elision".

Can anyone help me with simple examples how xvalue expression are involved in the situation 3, 4 and 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> situation 3, 4 and 7.

7 (discarded expression) is the easiest:

```
42; // materialize and discard
std::string{"abc"}; // materialize and discard
```

3 (doing things to array rvalue) requires knowing how to make them

```
using arr_t = int[2][3];
int a = arr_t{}[0][0]; // have to materialize to be able to subscript
```

4 (making an std::initializer_list) is what it says on the tin

```
std::initializer_list<std::string>{
  "abc"s,
  "def"s
}; // have to materialize the two strings
   // to place them in the secret array pointed to by the list
```

Comment: "secret" array means "temporary" array?

Comment: @OxO yes, though it could also be burned into `.rodata` forever